# Tem como pegar a porcentagem do desvio padrão (R)?

Tags: r

Por exemplo..

Tenho uma série de valores (preços) relacionados a um produto em várias datas diferentes.

Preciso pegar a porcentagem de alteração desse valor.

Atualmente, os preços estão dando um desvio padrão de 120,00,só que eu queria esse resultado em porcentagem. Tipo, os preços variaram em 20% nesses dias específicos.

Como fazer isso no R?

Comment: *"os preços variaram em 20%"* em relação à média? Isso é o [coeficiente de variação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_de_varia%C3%A7%C3%A3o) multiplicado por cem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se pretende saber o desvio padrão relativo à média, isso é o [coeficiente de variação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coeficiente_de_varia%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Para ter em porcentagem basta multiplicar por cem.

Programar o CV em R é um problema muito fácil de resolver.

```
coefVar <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE){
  sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
}

set.seed(9580)    # Torna os resultados reprodutíveis

x <- runif(100, 0, 20)

coefVar(x)
#[1] 0.621354

coefVar(x)*100    # Em porcentagem
#[1] 62.1354
```

Tendo em conta o comentário sobre o resultado de um cálculo da função, isto é o que me dá:

```
y <- c(772.8, 147.28, 993.72)
coefVar(y)*100
#[1] 68.82238
```

Parece estar certo.

Comment: Hum.. Eu até tentei fazer isso, mas o resultado está ficando confuso. Por exemplo, só o sd deu 336.353.
Só que quando eu vou rodar a porcentagem da variação dá 63.62789. 

Esses 63.62789 é em cima de que? 

Ps.: Meu conhecimento em estatística é bem baixo. Se puder me explicar· :)

Comment: Por exemplo, acabei de fazer aqui. Tenho esses três valores, 772.8 / 147.28 / 993.72. Com um desvio padrão de 439.0409 e média de 637.9333, se eu dividir o sd pela média dá 0.6882238. Seguindo sua lógica, eu teria que multiplicar por 100 que daria 68,82%. Porque o resultado usando o seu código não tá dando isso?

Comment: Utilizando o meu código dá exatamente isto: `[1] 68.82238`.

Comment: Eu devia tá fazendo algo errado. Valeu .  :)